# Is it correct that predication in WHERE is not about the relation in the FROM in SQL query?

Tags: sql, database

This is problem about answer to "Database System Concepts(6th Edition)" Practice Exercise 3.2-a.

> This error is not included in the errata. I think this should be updated    to the errata of this book!

Give four relations:

1. grade_points

   ***grade_points(grade, points)***

   If grade = 'A+', points = 4,

   if grade = 'A-', points = 3.7

   just like this ...
2. student

   ***student(ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred)***

   ID is the id of the student, name is his name, dept_name is his department name, tot_cred is his the total credits he got.
3. course

   ***course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits)***
4. takes

   ***takes(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)***

   The ID is the student ID who takes the course of course_id, the grade is the level he got in this course.

**The problem is:**

> Find the total grade-points earned by the student with ID 12345,
>   across all courses taken by the student.

The solution given by Answers of textbook is this:

```
(select sum(credits * points)

from (takes natural join course) natural join grade_points

where ID = '12345')

union

(select 0

from student -- This is relation "student"

where takes.ID = '12345' and -- takes.ID should be student.ID ???

      not exists (select * from takes where takes.ID = '12345'))
```

> If a student has not taken any course, we would expect to give 0 as the answer.

I think the first "takes.ID" in last where clause should be "student.ID" to indicate that he is a student and then check whether he takes courses. Is the using of "takes.ID" legal and correct? If it is correct, why?

Comment: You're right, this `takes.ID` will result in an error message because `takes` is not in the tables listed in `FROM`. Btw, this query as-is will not provide a correct answer as the row with zero is always returned, you need to wrap it in another Derived Table and then `SUM` both rows. Or better do a `COALESCE(sum(credits * points),0)` in the 1st Select to get rid of the `UNION`

Comment: Which version of the book are you using - there might be an erratta list or might be fixed in a later version. The entire query seems a rather convoluted way to solve it so might be an old version?

Comment: I think this is a error of this book's practice answers. Thanks for answer my question!

Comment: A book on SQL recommending natural joins is somewhat special anyway :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just and error in the book's practice answers. I will email the authors to update the errata.